# Saving UI layout (but not the scene)

Tags: interface

I understand "Save Start-up file". I like this method of customising/personalising blender.

Is it possible to use "Save Start-up file" but only saving the U.I data and not the mesh/materials/lights/etc data.

Kinda annoying if I like a windows position in a certain way (while working on something) I can't just save "Save Start-up U.I layout".

I've just been memorising the layout, loading up a clean project, rearranging the windows (sometimes loading up the project back up, comparing the difference. Then committing to "Save Start-up file" so there are no lingering objects, materials.

Sometimes this is a 1 button answers xD

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the layout you want and then duplicate it from the top bar.
Either click the <kbd>+</kbd> sign at the end of the top menu bar and select <kbd>Duplicate Current</kbd>:

[image]

or right-click on a layout and select <kbd>Duplicate</kbd> from the popup menu:

[image]

You'll see from my toolbar shown above that I have two shader layouts for instance, one with the windows arranged vertically and one horizontally (<kbd>Shading T_B</kbd> and <kbd>Shading L_R</kbd>) and two animation ones with different layouts. That menu also allows you to move your required layout to the start of the toolbar. I've not tried it, but I assume the first layout on the toolbar is the default one on startup.
You'll need to save your startup file once you have everything set up.

Comment: But if you were in a heavy scene with 1000 objects with random materials and tweaked the U.I (and liked it that way), your start-up file would consist of tweaked U.I and 1000 objects with random materials. I'm just after only U.I data being saved

Comment: So you save your complete scene, delete all the contents, add a new layout in the top bar and then save your startup file.

Comment: Aye. It's the deleting the complete scene every time I want to change my default layout that is problematic. I was just checking if there was a way just for interface only mode.

Comment: Ah ok. Can't see any way of doing that. You can of course **load** a file without loading the UI with it, but I assume you realise that. (In the file selector, press 'N' and uncheck Load UI.)